# sed search string with special character in a file

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed

I have to search string in in file searchstring is Ev_SQL_DIR=/dev/mirror/sched/sql
and to be searched in file having content as per below

```
cat file.txt
Ev_SQL_DIR=/dev/mirror/sched/sql
Ev_TRIG_DIR=/hubdev/mirror/sched/trig
Ev_DB2_ENC_STR={iisenc}lasdbDxMsMFVOJBK0Gsg==
EV_COMPILEOPT=-c -O -fPIC -Wno-deprecated -m64 -mtune=generic -mcmodel=small
```

I used `sed -n '/$searchstring/p' file.txt` but it gives below error and I tried to escape also tried to use regex but not able to get it right. any inputs?

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 24: unknown command: `S'
```

Comment: I want to search exact string Ev_SQL_DIR=/dev/mirror/sched/sql and do not want to get results like Ev_SQL_DIR=/dev/mirror/sched/sql/new etc

Comment: The use `grep` as was already suggested in the deleted comment.

Comment: What's `$searchstring` ? I assume it contains `/` ?

Comment: @Aaron *searchstring is Ev_SQL_DIR=/dev/mirror/sched/sql*. It does contain `/`

Answer (score 0):

You should use double quotes `"`. Otherwise Bash will not replace the variable `$searchstring` for its content. Also, try to use it as:

```
$ searchstring="Ev_SQL_DIR=/dev/mirror/sched/sql"
$ sed -n "/${searchstring//\//\\/}/p" file.txt
Ev_SQL_DIR=/dev/mirror/sched/sql
```

It seems that you *must* use the `/`. Using `#` doesn't work for me as well :s

An alternative to this is to use `grep`. I think it's better in this case, because you do not have to worry about the slashes.

```
$ grep "$searchstring" file.txt 
Ev_SQL_DIR=/dev/mirror/sched/sql
```

I usually only use `sed` when I want to replace something, and `grep` when I want to retrieve a part of a file or string. Grep also has a regex option (-E).

Comment: Getting a blank value after trying sh-4.1$ echo $searchstring
Ev_SQL_DIR=/dev/mirror/sched/sql
-sh-4.1$ var=`sed -n "#$searchstring#p" file.txt`
-sh-4.1$ echo $var

Comment: @Bayou `#` denotes a comment in `sed` commands, which is why it didn't work. I often use `@` as an alternative delimiter, but it's best to pick a character that is guaranteed not to appear in the delimited pattern (here you'd want a character that isn't a valid character for a linux filename)

Comment: @Bayou - as per your suggestion I used `grep` instead of `sed` and it worked and I'm not going to get multiple results as per my comment. Multiple results were going to occur for different requirement and I was able to handle it using `sed`. Thanks

Comment: @Aaron I didn't know that, thanks. I often use use `s#/path/to/dir/#/something/else#`. I guess that it's only a comment when the text starts with `#`. @SumedhPatil you're welcome, I've just learned something myself :-)

Comment: Actually my comment was somewhat incorrect/irrelevant, I'm sorry. Alternative delimiters can be used for `s` (and that includes `#` as you mentionned), but not for `/test/` where you're stuck to escaping slashes.Trying to replace the slashes by `#` would have indeed made it a comment though, suppressing any error. Edit: just checked `man sed` and there's an alternate format for `GNU sed` at least: `\XpatternX`, where any character can be used instead of X